# Convert pip requirements.txt to conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, dockerfile

How to rewrite the following Dockerfile to use `conda` instead of `pip`? So there is no need to install pip separately. Does it have to create a new conda environment?

```
FROM .....
COPY myproj /myproj
RUN /apps/miniconda/bin/conda install --yes pip
RUN /apps/miniconda/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip install -r /myproj/requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["/apps/miniconda/bin/python"]
CMD ["/myproj/start.py"]
```

Comment: Does this not currently work? Moreover, without further motivation, I don't see why Conda should be used at all. If the whole container is just for running a Python script and users never need Conda or multiple environments, it would make more sense to use a system- or user-level Python with Pip. More to your question, though, there is no clean and reliable way to convert from PyPI to Conda package specifications - because Conda is more than a Python package manager, name conflicts force some packages to go by different names and no one maintains a conversion table, AFAIK.

Comment: The conda (miniconda) is already available in the image so I was trying to reduce the time to install `pip`. Maybe I should use `conda list` to generate conda requirement file first.